# Access object of one custom view to another Customview, created on Activty class

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

My actual problem: I have an array in `CustomView1` class. And I want to access it in `CustomView2` class. And when it will fill, I have to call `view2.invalidate()`.

This is my activity class:

```
public class TestApp extends Activity {

        CustomView1 view1;

        CustomView2 view2;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            view1 = (CustomView1) findViewbyId(R.id.CustomViewID1);
            view2 = (CustomView2) findViewbyID(R.id.CustomViewID2);

        }
    }
```

This is my first `CustomView` class . Here I want to call `view2.invalidate()`.

```
public class CustomView1 extends View {

    byte[] bytearray = new byte[200];

    public CustomView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @override
    onDraw() {
        view2.invalidate();
    }

}
```

And this is my second `CustomView` class. Here I want to access the same object of `CustomView1`(i.e `view1` object  ) class that I have created in Activity class.

```
public class CustomView2 extends View {

    public CustomView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to access like this? Any other idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work you need to have a reference of those views inside your custom views classes.
Something like this in `CustomView1` (same logic is applied for `CustomView2`):

```
public class CustomView1 extends View
{

    byte[] bytearray  = new byte[200];
    private CustomView2 view2;

    public CustomView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
       super(context, attrs);  
    }

    public void setCustomView2(CustomView2 view2) 
    {
       this.view2 = view2;
    }

    @override 
    onDraw()
    {
       if(view2 != null) //If view2 is not already set, we do not want a null pointer exception to occur
       {
          view2.invalidate();
       }
    }

}
```

To use it, you need something like this:

```
public class TestApp extends Activity  
{ 

   CustomView1  view1 ;
   CustomView2  view2 ;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
       setContentView(R.layout.main); 

       view1   = (CustomView1) findViewbyId(R.id.CustomViewID1);
       view2   = (CustomView2) findViewbyID(R.id.CustomViewID2);

       view1.setCustomView2(view2);
       view2.setCustomView1(view1);

   }  
}
```

**EDIT:**
You can create another custom constructor for your `CustomView1` class in addition to the one you already have. Something like this:

```
public CustomView1(Context context) 
{
     super(context);  
}
```

This way you avoid passing a null `AttributeSet` to your view and you call your custom view like this: `CustomView1 view1 = new CustomView1(context)`.

The `public CustomView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor is used to handle the situation that you declare you custom view through a layout xml file  and not programmatically. You will need to set the layout properties of your view programmatically that way. Check [this](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html) for help in doing so.

Comment: can I create a object like this on CustomView1  class .  CustomView2   = new CustomView2(context, null);

Comment: I am new in Object oriented programming. Can we  use  this approach for normal  class also?

Comment: @user2737044 For your first question, i have updated my answer. Yes you can use this aproach for normal classes (classes that are not Activities, Services etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a `CustomView2 view2;` member inside your `CustomView1` class. At the layout time, just tell view1 what is its view2.

This may look like this:

```
view2 = (CustomView2)findViewById(R.id.view2);
view1 = (CustomView1)findViewById(R.id.view1);
view1.setView2(view2);
```